# Can home-brewed mead be dangerous?

Tags: health, home-brew, mead

I want to home-brew some mead because why not , plus it seems pretty easy to do.

My question is :

Can any mistake in the brewing process make the drink "poisonous" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using honey, water and yeast. Then the answer is NO. But alcohol is a poisonous substance if not used properly. You cannot make it strong enough to "poison" you in the traditional sense. Could you poison yourself by drinking too much of it, sure it's possible. But, there are no by-products from the fermentation process that would "poison" you. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot , that's exactly the answer I was waiting for !

Comment: Also assuming proper sanitation, but that has nothing to do with mead in particular (would apply to any homebrewing).

Comment: There seems to be a lot of worry about poisoning just recently - have I missed something?

Comment: I really think @MonicaCellio's comment about sanitisation should be first and foremost in the answer. They are asking "Can **any** mistake in the brewing process...". The one difference I found between mead brewing and other brewing is you don't boil the mix so contamination is slightly more likely. Even with bad sanitisation from what I can tell making something toxic is unlikely because the alcohol kills most things, you will just create something undrinkable. I've heard mead has a bad reputation, but I'm not sure why.